# GEO2D index implementation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, 2d, geospatial

I am using GEO2D index (for data stored as points on a two-dimensional plane) in MongoDB and wondering how it is working under the hood.
There is this [page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) but it did not mention which algorithm it uses.
Is it using [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, like all other MongoDB indexes it's a B-Tree:

> **Behavior of Indexes**
>
> All indexes in MongoDB are B-tree indexes, which can efficiently
>   support equality matches and range queries. The index stores items
>   internally in order sorted by the value of the index field. The
>   ordering of index entries supports efficient range-based operations
>   and allows MongoDB to return sorted results using the order of
>   documents in the index.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/

There is an open ticket to implement R-Tree indexing for Geospatial but it's old so it does not appear to be coming any time soon:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3551

Comment: Thx, very helpful ! I also found this interesting slides:http://fr.slideshare.net/nknize/rtree-spatial-indexing-with-mongodb-mongodc